# How to create a conditional format in excel 2007 from another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

- I have a sheet with 4 fields spanning `A3:D3`
- in `D3` I have a conditional format that turns the cell yellow if it equals the word "no contact"

How can I get Cells `A3:C3` to also turn yellow if this is the case, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Select the cells from A3 to D3 then click on the **Conditional Formatting** then on the **New Rule...**

[image]

after that choose the option **Use a formula to determine which cells to format** and then write the following as the rule `=$D3="no contact"` click on the **Format** select the Yellow color and click Ok, and Ok again.

[image]

After that you can click on **Conditional Formatting** and then on **Manage Rules...**
to see your rule.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for the detailed instructions, but surely the OP can just use the Format Painter?

Answer (score 2):

In your Conditional Formatting edit the `Applies To` range

```
$A$3:$D$3
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Format Painter, unless you have further rules in `D3` that you do not want applied to `A3:C3`.

Select `D3`, click 'Format Painter' (in the 'Clipboard' group on the 'Home' tab) and then select `A3:C3`.

Comment: I had already specified that in my answer, so no need for down vote :)